# Проверка наличия класса у вложенного элемента

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую! Помогите решить следующую задачу:
Есть форма, в которой есть n-кол-во `div.component`, нужно сделать так, что если в родительском `div.component` есть `div.component_option_thumbnail.selected`, то `span.amount` копируем в конец `h3`.
По сути, если `.component_option_thumbnail` имеет класс `.selected`, то в `h3` копируем `span.amount`.

```html
<form>
   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">1000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">2000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">3000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Заранее, спасибо!

Comment: Не очень ясна суть задачи. Какого `h3`? Внутрь него переносить или рядом? И в чём у вас возникла проблема? Уточните пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваше описание задачи, то вот так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('form .component').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('.component_option_thumbnail').hasClass('selected')){
      $(this).find('h3').append($(this).find('span.amount').clone());
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">1000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">2000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">3000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто помог! Есть усложненная версия этой задачи http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/613887/16275

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.component').each( function( index, comp_node ){
    const $amount = $( '.component_option_thumbnail.selected .amount', comp_node ); 
    $( 'h3', comp_node ).append( $amount.text() ); 
} );
```

Константа `$amount` будет содержать `jquery` обёртку над узлом с классом `.amount`, который содержится в текущем узле (`comp_node`) и у которого есть предок с классами `.component_option_thumbnail`  и `.selected` одновременно.
Если такого узла нет то в `$amount` будет пустой `jquey` объект.

Метод `text` для непустого `jquery` объекта вернёт тест содержащийся во всех узлах выборки (конкатенация текстов всех узлов).
Для пустого объекта вернётся пустая строка, за счет этого нет необходимости проверять наличие или отсутствие `.content_option_thumbnail` c `.selected`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".component").each(function(){
 if($(this).find(".component_option_thumbnail").hasClass("selected"))
 {  
  $(this).find("h3").append($(".component_option_thumbnail.selected").find(".amount").html());
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">1000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">2000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">3000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```