# Решения задачи по вложенности элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите решить задачу (еще одну для тех, кто мне уже помог): 
Есть форма, в которой есть n-кол-во **div.component**.
При клике на **a.toggle** добавляется класс **.selected** к диву **component_option_thumbnail** (это делает другой скрипт).

Наша задача, отследить клик по **a.toggle** и если в родительском **div.component** есть **div.component_option_thumbnail.selected**, то **span.amount** копируем в конец **h3**.

```
 <form>
    <div class="component">
        <div class="component-title">
            <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component-inner">
            <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
                <a href="" class="toggle"></a>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="amount">1000</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="component">
        <div class="component-title">
            <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component-inner">
            <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
                <a href="" class="toggle"></a>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="amount">2000</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="component">
        <div class="component-title">
            <h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="component-inner">
            <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
                <a href="" class="toggle"></a>
                <span class="price">
                    <span class="amount">3000</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Пробовал вот, но не получается:

```
(function($) {
            $('form .component').each(function() {
                $('.toggle').click(function() {
                    console.log('Клик');
                  if($('.component').find('.component_option_thumbnail').hasClass('selected')){
                        console.log('Компонент найден');
                       $(this).find('h3').append($(this).find('.amount').clone());
                     };
                 });
             });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: А самому подумать головой и приспособить старый скрипт нельзя?

Comment: Не хватает знаний синтаксиса, к сожалению( Попробовал несколько вариантов - не получилось.

Comment: Что именно не получилось?

Comment: .amount не клонируется в h3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так (не тестировал). Ну и естественно нужно чтобы этот обработчик срабатывал после того как .selected уже добавлен предыдущим обработчиком.

```
(function($) {
    $('form').on('click', '.toggle', function() {
        var divThumbnail = $(this).parent();
        if (divThumbnail.hasClass('selected')) {
            var titleH3 = divThumbnail.parent().parent().find('H3');
            divThumbnail.find('span.amount').clone().appendTo(titleH3);
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

По вашему описанию, эта задача решается так:

```js
$(function() {
  $('a.toggle').click(function() {
    $('.component_option_thumbnail').each(function() {
      if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
      }else{
        $(this).addClass('selected');
      };
    });
    return false;
  });
    
  $('a.toggle').click(function() {
    $('form .component').each(function() {
      if($(this).find('.component_option_thumbnail').hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).find('h3').append($(this).find('span.amount').clone());
      };
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="" class="toggle">Нажали :)</a>

<form>
   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 1</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail selected">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">1000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 2</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">2000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="component">
      <div class="component-title">
         <h3>Заголовок 3</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="component-inner">
         <div class="component_option_thumbnail">
            <span class="price">
               <span class="amount">3000</span>
            </span>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```